# Праздник: романтичный или романтический?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные

Писала поздравления с 8 Марта, и меня заклинило: **романтичный праздник** или **романтический**?
Я бы написала "романтический", но как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос на самом деле одновременно и простой - и не очень.
Я постараюсь покороче, дабы не пугать несущественными для практики подробностями.

Слова романтичный и романтический - частичные синонимы. 
Оба имеют ряд значений, сводящихся к тому, что романтичный относится к романтизму или романтике, а романтический - к романтичности и романтикам. Но вся сложность в том, что все эти слова (романтизм, романтика, романтичность, романтики) в свою очередь имеют целый ряд значений, частично пересекающихся... 
Скорее всего в нашем случае "романтичный" относится к характеристике восприятия внешнего мира, а в этом значении "романтичный" и "романтический" - синонимы.
Т.е. обе формы допустимы. Тем не менее сложившаяся практика употребления отдаёт предпочтение форме "романтический": *романтический праздник, ужин, романтическое путешествие*.

Answer (score 3):

Толковый словарь русского языка Ушакова:
РОМАНТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое; в качестве кратк. форм употр. романти́чен, -чна, -чно (книжн.).
1. только полн. формы. Прил. к романтизм в 1 знач. Романтическая школа. Романтическая поэзия. Романтическая музыка.
2. Содержащий в себе романтизм (во 2 знач.), романтику (во 2 знач.) или склонный к ней; свойственный романтикам; являющийся романтиком; мечтательно настроенный, наивно-возвышенный. Романтическое настроение. Романтическая дама, если бы ей попались мои записки, тотчас бы повесила нос. Достоевский. Р. вкус. Р. характер.
3. То же, что романтический в 3 знач. Р. вздох. Романтические похождения.

РОМАНТИЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно (книжн.).
То же, что романтический во 2 знач.(Только во втором) Р. характер.
В ЕГЭ есть подобные задания. Но в школе такие пары слов называют паронимами, созвучными словами. Это как адресат и адресант.

Comment: Как Вы думаете, способен человек, априори не сведующий, понять разницу по этим цитатам из словаря? Тогда уж дано приводить всю цепочку ссылок на романтику, романтизм и проч. - а там опять по нескольку значений, тоже частично синонимичных, частично паронимичиных...    

А ответа так и сформулировано.
ЗЫ Ничего личного, просто поставьте себя на место спрашивающего.

Comment: Праздник не бывает романтический. Романтическая может быть допустим, традиция дарить дамам цветы. Праздник бывает: радостный, официальный, народный, религиозный, национальный итд.

Answer (score 3):

Романтичный юноша, но романтический ужин

Comment: А Мастер какой? У Булгакова - романтический.